# How do I write this SQL query in Mongodb syntax?

Tags: sql, mongodb

How do I write this SQL query in Mongodb syntax?

```
select a.title 
from movies as a 
inner join ratings as b on a.movieId=b.movieId 
where a.genres like '%Children%' 
and b.rating>3 
group by a.title;
```

Comment: The MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-conditions-using-query-operators) are really helpful. Give them a read and update your question with where you need help.

Comment: oh joining in MongoDB ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575722/how-to-do-inner-joining-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

For this SQL Query:

```
select movies.title 
from movies 
inner join ratings on movies.movieId=ratings.movieId 
where movies.genres like '%Children%' 
and ratings.rating>3 
group by movies.title;
```

The equivalent MongoDB Query is: (included sort and limit as well, remove if not required)

```
db.movies.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "ratings",
                "localField" : "movieId",
                "foreignField" : "movieId",
                "as" : "ratings_docs"
            }
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "ratings_docs" : {
                    "$ne" : [ ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "ratings_docs" : {
                    "$arrayElemAt" : [
                        "$ratings_docs",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match" : {
                "genres" : /^.*Children.*$/is,
                "ratings_docs.rating" : {
                    "$gt" : 3
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "title" : "$title"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project" : {
                "title" : "$_id.title"
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "_id" : -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit" : 100
        }
    ]
)
```

You can also generate the equivalent mongodb query anytime from the tools. like in my case I am using `No Sql Booster for MongoDB`.  I am also using free version of `No Sql Booster for MongoDB`

**Steps that you can follow:**

- **STEP 1:** Connect your Mongo DB Query String, and select this `SQL` as shown in image:

[image]

- **STEP 2:** You wll see a text area with `mb.runSQLQuery()` as shown below. You can write any query, and click on Code. The code will be generated below as shown in image. Don't worry, it converts all the queries, doesnot connect on the database.

[image]